# Hide String Array Value in Spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-spinner

I am using two Spinners and populating both using same String array :

```
final String[] arrayMonths = { "January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May",
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December" };
```

Now i would like to make a small change, i don't want to show `december` in **spinner1** and `January` in **spinner2**.

So where i have to make change in my code to get this done ?

**CODE**

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (ConnectedSpinnersStartEnd.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayMonths);

 spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Why not using ArrayList with WeakReference ? because you can easy perform remove operation on it before sending to Adapter class as data-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier than you think. The first step is to moving from the array to ArrayList, which gives you more flexibility, and submit it to the `ArrayAdapter` instead of the `Array`

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(arrayMonths));
mList.remove("December");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (ConnectedSpinnersStartEnd.this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mList);
```

on `onItemSelected`, if I understand correctly, you want to remove the selected item from the first spinner and add it to the second's one,

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        String str1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (spinner2.getAdapter() == null) {
               ArrayList<String> list =  new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(arrayMonths));
               list.remove("January");
               ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ConnectedSpinnersStartEnd.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
               spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I wrote it on top of my head, check for typo

Comment: wow, it took ten minus to write the whole thing... Hang on, I'll update the whole thing

Comment: I did update the thing. Use ArrayList, and call `mList.remove("December");` to remove december from the dataset of the first spinner. About the second one I am not sure about the *when*, but you can do the same thing. Have a look to the update

Answer (score 0):

You can use sublist after converting your array to list:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

like: `monthsList.subList(0,11)` and `monthsList.subList(1,12)`

Comment: similar to blackbelt's answer,
ArrayList<String> list =  new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(arrayMonths));
And then instead of removing the elements, just use sublist function on that list and pass to adapter.
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ConnectedSpinnersStartEnd.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list.subList(0,11)); and similarly, 1,12 for other case.